# Mass remove passwords from rar archives

Tags: rar, winrar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove password protection from compressed files](https://superuser.com/questions/115692/how-to-remove-password-protection-from-compressed-files)

Is there a way to (I'm using WinRAR; demo, but I'm willing to change it to whatever is needed) mass remove passwords from a bunch of files ?

Problem description: for reasons unknown to me, some archiving was done for two-and-something years in RAR format, and all archives have passwords. I have a list of them, them all being similar (mostly something like John-03, John-04, John-05 ... e.g. name-month ...) but I need to manipulate the files at large, and it is a real problem removing and or dearchiving all those files, while entering passwords manually.

What would be my best options concerning ?

Ideally, I'm looking for some kind of archiver which tries out a predefined list of passwords, and asks only if non of them cracks the safe. Afaik, WinRAR has no such feature.

Answer (score 0):

WinRAR comes with a command-line tool `rar`, which can be scripted to extract and re-create archives.